# Linked Server only for Select Statements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server, etl

In linked server concept can we run only select queries like below ?

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER_NAME], 'SELECT * FROM DATABASE_NAME..TABLENAME')
```

I have a job which runs through Linked server.

I have added the AOAG Listener as Linked server in the source server and this connects to PROD server and runs the query.

But the query is very big...so how this works through Linked server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have linked your servers, you can query any server using `[servername].databasename.schema.object` from any one of the two servers.